# How Do I Convert from int to float?

Tags: java, floating-point, int, type-conversion, rounding

I am tasked with creating a program that rounds a number such as 2.7 to 3 and 2.5 to 2. I have already written a code that does this but my teacher wants the output in int. (i.e. 2.7 = 3).
Here is what I have:

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class HandsOn14JamesVincent {
       public static void main(String[] args){
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter a decimal number and I will round it."); 
           float num = input.nextFloat();
           float num1 = Math.round(num);
           float num2 = num1 - num;
           if (num2 <= .3)
           System.out.println(Math.ceil(num));
           if (num2 > .3) 
           System.out.println(Math.floor(num));
       } 
   }
```

It displays the correct number, but it displays them in float (2.0). I can't seem to figure out how to convert them. 
I tried multiplying the num by (int) but it didn't work. 
Please Help!!

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing to 0.5 not to 0.3? And can't you just cast to an int? `(int) floatingPointNumber`

Comment: I have to use .3 so a number such as 1.7 rounds up, and and a number such as 1.6 rounds down. That's what the assignment is.

Comment: FWIW, `(int)num` is not called *multiplying* with `(int)`, it is called *casting* to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

James you can cast a float to an int and it will drop the decimal part of the number.

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class HandsOn14JamesVincent {
       public static void main(String[] args){
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter a decimal number and I will round it."); 
           float num = input.nextFloat();
           float num1 = Math.round(num);
           float num2 = num1 - num;
           if (num2 <= .3)
           System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(num));
           if (num2 > .3) 
           System.out.println((int)Math.floor(num));
       } 
   }
```

Notice the `(int)`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I created a float var call numF so i give num to numF `float numf = num` then I use the numF with the same value of num in meth operations

Comment: Granted, the question title is misleading. The OP wants to convert a **float** to an **int** (and not the other way round, as stated in the question title). Nonetheless, how does assigning a `float` variable to another `float` variable convert it to an `int`?